# PostgreSQL 8.1 (Greenplum) - User defined type as an array example

Tags: arrays, postgresql, types, greenplum, user-defined

How do one create an array of a user defined type in PostgreSQL 8.1 (Greenplum)?

I have the type:

```
create type tp_keyval as (
  key_nm   text
 ,key_vals text[]
);
```

I would like an array something like:

```
v_keyval_set tp_keyval[];
```

According to the documentation it can be done and should work .. 
I even tried it with the underscore as indicated in the documentation, but to no avail.

```
v_keyval_set _tp_keyval;
```

Could someone please provide an example of how to do this.

Regards,
Johan

Comment: If your type is `tp_keyval` then `tp_keyval[]` and `tp_keyval ARRAY` (SQL compatible) should work (`_tp_keyval` is only for internal usage - implementation detail - do not use it explicitly). *but to no avail* - What is your error message? Can you provide some more context (f.ex. the whole stored procedure)?

Comment: Hi all,Unfortunately i have moved on from the client and no longer have access to the Greenplum (PostgrfeSQL) database.

Comment: BTW: tp_keyval [] did not work, I tried that first.